# If Array.prototype.slice() method returns shallow copy why does changing the value of sliced array does not change the original

Tags: javascript

The Array.prototype.slice() method [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) says

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

If that is the case why does modifying the array returned by the Array.prototype.slice() does not change the original value.

```
> a = [1, 2, 3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> b = a.slice(0)
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> b[0] = 4
4
> b
[ 4, 2, 3 ]
> a // the expected output should be the same as output of b if b is shallowcopy of a.
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

May be copy on write is happening while trying to modify the array **a**. If so is it technically correct to say that **Array.prototype.slice()** does return shallow copy.

Comment: *"why does modifying the array returned by the Array.prototype.slice() does not change the original value."* Because it's a shallow ***copy***, just like the docs you quoted states.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the expected output is __not__ the expected output.

Comment: @cookiemonster Then shouldn't the docs say it return deep copy. As per my understanding changing the shallow copy object will change the actual value at memory location which might be referred by many objects.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: If that was the definition, it would be a pointless exercise. You'd end up with the exact same Array. Might as well just do `b = a`. I think the issue may be that you don't understand the semantics of object assignment in JavaScript. Objects are reference types. What's assigned to the variable is a reference to the object, not the object itself. It's like a boxed pointer with limited and automatic dereferencing capabilities. So `b = a;` makes a copy of the reference, not the object/array itself. And a shallow copy is a copy of the members one level deep.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a.slice is a new array, it's not a pointer to the initial variable.

Comment: How does the term shallow copy in a language like c++ differ from javascript. My understanding is that change made to the shallow copy is reflected by all the objects which has a reference.

Comment: I do not know why you have that understanding.  A copy is just what it sounds like, a copy.  If you're thinking of a pointer, that's fine... but that's a pointer.

Comment: In c++ if an object contains several references to other objects, then copying that objects will also copy the references, but even that does not apply to literals